# Looking for jquery image gallery

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, fullscreen, thumbnails, image-gallery

I'm looking fo jquery gallery with

```
Lazy load
```

`Fullscreen mode` and

`thumbnail preview`.

could you suggest me something?

I have found flexslider but it hasn't Fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Try blueimp gallery. Highly customizable.
https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery